# Rename new files using old ones

Tags: file-management, mp3, music, playlists

I have a large music collection, and a good number of playlists that I have formed over the years.
All the music is neatly organised in a folder hierarchy.

I have managed to get my hands on higher quality versions of multiple albums, and would like to replace the low quality ones with these. But, that would mean that I have to build my playlists again from the scratch, as the new filenames will not be recognise in the old playlists. What is the best option for me to proceed?

One of the ways I thought would work was to see which filename of in new album is closest to the old one, and then rename it with the old filename (i.e. file named 01-Highway-to-Hell.mp3 in new album would be closest to highway_to_hell.mp3 in the old album). How do go about doing this renaming?

Comment: Do you want to keep the "low quality" files? Are there proper ID3 tags on the files?

Comment: So, the real problem is that old and new file names doesn't match and a potential script/program has to change some characters. But where should the script stop changing characters to get a match?

Comment: Under Linux it is at least doable (bear in mind that this is not an easy task), as long as the files in the old and new albums match one to one. Too bad that you are seeking a Windows based solutions.

Comment: I don't want to keep the low quality files. I just need to rename the new files as the old ones, so that my old paylists won't be affected
I'd be willing to accept a Linux solution as well

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://search.cpan.org/~suntong/File-FindSimilars-2.06/bin/findsimilars) will at least help you pair them up, but you've got lots to do next. Again, much easier if you know basic Linux command line tools.